# Node & MySQL: Can't end connection -> Async confusion

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, node-mysql

I'm trying to write a Node program that populates my MySQL database with data from files I have on disk. I may or may not be going about this the right way, but it's working. What I'm having trouble with is understanding how I should be handling allowing asynchronous functions to finish before the connection to the DB is ended. Ultimately, I'll be reading lots of data files, and insert them into the database like I did below. I could just use `readFileSync` instead of the asynchronous version, but I need to get a better handle on asynchronous functions.

When I insert the wine categories below, it works fine since it's not using an asynchronous function. However, when I use `readFile` to get data from a file, I get an error that connection ended before any of the queries were executed:

```
connection.connect( function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

// Take a table and the values, and insert a new row into a table
function insert_into( table, values ) {
    if( values instanceof Array ) {
        values = values.map( function( value ) {
            return '"' + value + '"';
        }).join(', ');
    } else {
        values = '"' + values + '"';
    }

    var statement = 'INSERT INTO ' + table + ' VALUES (NULL, ' + values + ')';
    connection.query( statement, function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log( values + " successfully added.");
    });
};

// Populate the wine_categories table
var wine_categories = [
    'red', 'white', 'rose', 'sparkling', 'fortified'
];

// Works fine when used alone
wine_categories.forEach( function( element ) {
    insert_into( 'wine_categories', element );
});

// Populate the countries table
// connection.end() runs before this finishes its job
fs.readFile( countries, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        var codes = Array.prototype.map.call( 
            data.split('\n'), function( country ) {
                return country.split('\t');
        });

        codes.forEach( function( country ) {
            if( country[1].length > 25 ) {
                country[1] = country[1].substring(0, 25);
            }
            insert_into( 'countries', country );
        });
    }
}); 

connection.end();
```

Obviously, `connection.end()` needs to happen after all of the inserts have completed, but I'm not sure how to handle that. I don't want it to be a callback for the `readFile` call because I'll ultimately have many of similar calls in this file.

How should I structure my code so that all of the queries execute and `connection.end()` runs when they're all finished? The answer is probably obvious to an asynchronous wiz...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using promises it would be like this:

```
pool.getConnectionAsync().then(function(connection) {
    // Populate the wine_categories table
    var wine_categories = [
        'red', 'white', 'rose', 'sparkling', 'fortified'
    ];
    var wineQueries = wine_categories.map(function(wine){
        return insert_into(connection, "wine_categories", wine);
    });

    var countryQueries = fs.readFileAsync(countries, "utf-8").then(function(data) {
        return data.split("\n").map(function(country) {
            country = country.split("\t")[1];
            if (country.length > 25) {
                country = country.substring(0, 25);
            }
            return insert_into(connection, "countries", country);
        });
    });

    Promise.all(wineQueries.concat(countryQueries))
        .then(function() {
            console.log("all done");
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log("error", e);
        })
        .finally(function() {
            connection.release();
        })
});
```

Pre-requisite code for the above

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Connection").prototype);
var pool = Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql").createPool({
    "user": "...",
    "password": "...",
    "database": "...",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "debug": false
}));

function insert_into(connection, table, values) {
    if( values instanceof Array ) {
        values = values.map(connection.escape, connection).join(', ');
    } else {
        values = connection.escape(values);
    }
    return connection
        .queryAsync('INSERT INTO ' + table + ' VALUES (NULL, ' + values + ')')
        .then(function() {
            console.log(values + " successfully added.");
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! With a minor modification to the `country` format, it worked. A couple follow questions: 1. If I have more insert queries that I want to use, can I just keep adding `.concat(queryName)` to `Promise.all`? 2. If additional tables have foreign keys for tables that are being populated, will I need to create a new pool that will run after this one?

Comment: @EmptyArsenal `Promise.all` takes an array of promises and returns a promise that will be fulfilled when all the promises in the original array are fulfilled. To run a query, get connection from the pool, then use the connection to run queries and finally release the connection. Like this: http://pastebin.com/JhyvFhAS

Comment: @EmptyArsenal you can make a helper function like this to make it even easier http://pastebin.com/5twg6YE1

Comment: You have `Async` at the end of a number of your functions. Is that a Bluebird convention, or is `readFileAsync` a synonym for `readFile`?

Comment: @EmptyArsenal `promisifyAll` creates methods on the object with `Async` suffix. So for example `readFile` becomes `readFileAsync`. There is normally no promise returning methods in most libraries like fs and mysql. Suffix is used to avoid overwriting.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `insert_into` is also asynchronous, you may want to use something like [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback) to handle inserting your records. It has a convenient callback that will be called when all records are inserted, because only at that point do you want to close the connection:

```
async.each(codes, function(country, callback) {
  if ( country[1].length > 25 ) {
    country[1] = country[1].substring(0, 25);
  }
  insert_into( 'countries', country, callback ); // !! read below
}, function(err) {
  // TODO: handle any errors
  ...
  // Here, all countries are inserted.
  connection.end();
});
```

However, this means that `insert_into` should also be made to accept a callback (using the common Node convention `function(err, result)`) that will be called when the record has been inserted. In the code above, I'm using the callback provided by `async` directly, meaning that once your `insert_into` is done, it will call the `async` callback signaling that this iteration of `each` is done.

**EDIT**: you can rewrite `insert_into` so it looks like this:

```
function insert_into( table, values, callback ) {
  ...
  connection.query(..., function(err) {
    callback(err);
  });
}
```

Since you don't need the actual result from `connection.query`, you only have to pass `err` (instead of throwing it).

Tip: assuming that you're using [`node-mysql`](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), you may want to take a look at the docs on how it can help you with [escaping](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I added the `insert_into` function into the code. I see that your suggestions look much more node-like, which I'm still getting the hang of. So, in this case, I could just log success or something as a callback and that would be sufficient?

Comment: @EmptyArsenal see my edit for a suggestion on how to rewrite `insert_into` to make it fit into the `async` workflow